# Fill Out Array of Objects to add 0 values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a dynamic array which for downstream purposes needs to have all properties define for all objects.

If I have this array:

```
[
{"Header":"1","Apples":10},
{"Header":"2","Apples":10, "Oranges":153},
{"Header":"3","Oranges":280, "Pears":200},
{"Header":"4","Oranges":1165}
]
```

How do I fill it out to infill zero values for properties where they exist elsewhere in the array, but not in that object.

Essentially I need to up with this:

```
[
{"Header":"1","Apples":10, "Oranges":0,   "Pears":0},
{"Header":"2","Apples":10, "Oranges":153, "Pears":0},
{"Header":"3","Apples":0,  "Oranges":280, "Pears":200},
{"Header":"4","Apples":0,  "Oranges":1165,"Pears":0}
]
```

Header property is essentially the id of each object

Comment: Ah, the keyword I was missing in my search was setting keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the existing property values by pushing each item's properties to an array (with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)), then using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the unique.

Then, map over each item in `arr` and in the loop, loop through the existing property values and check whether the current item has that property. If not, set the value of that property to `0`.

```js
const arr = [
    {"Header":"1","Apples":10},
    {"Header":"2","Apples":10, "Oranges":153},
    {"Header":"3","Oranges":280, "Pears":200},
    {"Header":"4","Oranges":1165}
]


const properties = [...new Set(arr.map(e => Object.keys(e)).flat())]

const result = arr.map(e => (properties.forEach(f => !e.hasOwnProperty(f) ? e[f] = 0 : ''), e))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
{"Header":"1","Apples":10},
{"Header":"2","Apples":10, "Oranges":153},
{"Header":"3","Oranges":280, "Pears":200},
{"Header":"4","Oranges":1165}
];

// get unique keys
let objWithAllProp = arr.reduce((acc, item) => ({...acc, ...item}));

// Get keys as an array and Create an object with all keys set to the default value to 0
let uniqueObjectWithAllProp = Object.keys(objWithAllProp).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = 0
  return acc;
}, {});

// Replace all default values with original, so if key not present in original item, it will be available from uniqueObjectWithAllProp and value default to 0
let result = arr.map((item) => ({...uniqueObjectWithAllProp , ...item}));

console.log(result);
```